# Issue in getting index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to store value in attribute in input tag which would like as follows.
The following code will repeat several times and the value for different radio can be saved using index.

```
<div data-bind="attr : { name : 'ex['+$index()+']' }>
<input type="radio" name="value" data-target="#modal" data-bind="click:fun.fill($index())"/>
</div>
```

From the above text box i can get the index of that input.And it points to a common modal function from bootstrap which opens a popup.

```
<div class="modal fade">
<select data-bind="attr:{name:'assignedResources['+$index()+'][repeatedType]'},
options : $root.repeats,value   : repeatedType"></select>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This is a sample of modal target.I want to call this modal as common.(i.e)it will be called from several places.I want to show appropriate popup for appropriate click from radio button.

But what i get is value of last index.Thats my problem

Comment: Can you please clarify a little what exactly you want to accomplish?

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte Hope this might be helpfull..

Comment: Did yo have a chance to look my answer? thanks dario

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but something like this...

```
this.abc = ko.observable('');
this.fun = {
     var that = this;

     fill: function(index) {
        console.log(that.abc());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response..But i have edited my question.Hope that might be helpful to give you a better solution

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you need an observable to store your value, and then you can access it by any other function on your viewModel.

This is a jsFiddle with my initial approach, let me know if is what you needed or clarify instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdarioduarte/X8Rc4/

With a model like this:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.abc = ko.observable('Value to store');

    this.fun = function() {
        alert(this.abc());
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Thanks,
Dario

Comment: Thanks for the response.Now i have edited my question.This might be helpful for you to understand

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand about your question. But, maybe this may help:

1) Obtains `index` of your input element `automatically` on page load to `viewModel` function maybe need `custom binding` to handle that:

e.g custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.saveIndex = {
     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var index = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        viewModel.fun(index); // accessing fun function on viewModel

        // You can also access that function using bindingContext.$root
        // bindingContext.$root.fun(index);
     }
};
```

e.g html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="saveIndex: $index()"/>
```

2) Store index to `input value attribute` using `attr binding`:

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { value: $index() }">
```

3) Send your `input attr value` to viewModel function onClick:

```
<input type="text" value="thisIsExampleValue" data-bind="click: function() { $root.fun($element.value); }">
```

You also can use event binding for this behavior, [Knockout.Event-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
<div data-bind="attr : { name : 'ex['+$index()+']' }>
<input type="radio" name="value" data-target="#modal" data-bind="click: function() { fun.fill($index()) }"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Now i have edited my question.This might be helpful for you to understand